# converting video to mjpeg file format

Tags: video-streaming

I hava a java program to stream mjpeg files.I am not able to find mjpeg file anywhere.can anyone help me how to get the file.Or tell me how to convert a file to mjpeg format? I have tried converting an avi file to mjpeg using total video converter but it didnt work.

Comment: Mencoder does it too. Here's a thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077573/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-mjpeg-codec-used-in-mencoder-vlc-and-ffmpeg

Answer (score 12):

Use ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec mjpeg -qscale 1 -an output.avi
```

Just substitute the input file with the one of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mencoder and libavc:

```
mencoder input.mp4 -o  output.mjpeg -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mjpeg -oac=copy
```